# Is there a timestamp for each output line from Jupyter Notebook cell output?

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to time how long it takes for a TPU to train via Colab (a Jupyter Notebook). Since TensorFlow logs to the cell output in Colab, I was going to get the total train time by grabbing the timestamp from when the TPU was initialized and stopped.

Comment: You want to get the execution time of each command in jupyter notebook cell?

Comment: Not exactly. I think I can do that by using Python's time library and doing the time.time() instruction before and after a command in a cell.

Instead what I'm trying to do is find out is if there's timestamps logged for each output. So for example, TensorFlow might log:

"INFO:tensorflow: some output1"
"INFO:tensorflow: some output2"
"INFO:tensorflow: some output3"

I'm trying to find the time it took to go from output1 to output3. (Basically a rudimentary way to find training time for an epoch using TPUs).

Comment: %time before each command in jupyter notebook cell will give the time required to execute each command rather than using python's time library

Comment: Thanks for this; however, it seems it's only used for CPU times for processing the instruction(s). I placed it right before the instruction that trains on a TPU, and the resulting times were measured in microseconds, which is definitely not accurate for the TPU. For reference: %time resulted in "CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 3 µs Wall time: 5.01 µs", when it took the TPU roughly 1 minute to train on 24 epochs. So %time is saying it took microseconds to process the instruction with the CPU but provides no insight on the time it took for the TPU to train. :/